# custom image picker as seen on Pinterest and other similar apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

How can I simulate the tab-bar/camera behavior in the picture?
I have seen many apps which shows the very similar behavior, and I suspect there could be a library for it?

You can tab on the camera icon in the tab bar controller.
[image]

It opens camera, and you can also access your album by clicking the button on the right.
[image]

Comment: Please refer the squareCam example of the apple's developer site [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011190)

Comment: And for retrieving images from camera-role use AssetsLibrary.framework

Comment: I have made one application like what you have explained here if need any help you can ask for help :)

Comment: @Aalok: Definitely, I could use your help. I thought I left comment the other day already, it's gone..

Comment: In my app i use navigation controller with one bottom bar (toolbar) with help of it if i click camerabutton it shows camera and if i click album button it shows album. Does it is helpful to you? if yes then i will post the code snippets :)

Comment: For showing album i use ELCimagePicker controller example available on github :)

Comment: For display the album i use [this](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController) example